# Parent and child multiselect dropdown

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a multi-select dropdown with parent and child relations. I found this link http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-enableCollapsibleOptGroups on the internet.

I am trying the below example where I am getting below errors:

> Access to font at 'http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>
> Access to font at 'http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>
> Access to font at 'http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

How can I avoid this CORS policy error? How do I verify checked or unchecked?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example-enableCollapsibleOptGroups-enableClickableOptGroups-enableFiltering-includeSelectAllOption').multiselect({
    enableClickableOptGroups: true,
    enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-example.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/prettify.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">

<select id="example-enableCollapsibleOptGroups-enableClickableOptGroups-enableFiltering-includeSelectAllOption" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Group 1">
    <option value="1-1">Option 1.1</option>
    <option value="1-2">Option 1.2</option>
    <option value="1-3">Option 1.3</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group 2">
    <option value="2-1">Option 2.1</option>
    <option value="2-2">Option 2.2</option>
    <option value="2-3">Option 2.3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/prettify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to copy all the files and run them on your local webserver. The issue is because you're leeching the content from a third party server

Comment: As I am a beginner I am not getting what files copy if you guide me that will be a great help

Comment: Either download the files to local or use CDN like https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: Every file which you're linking to on the `http://davidstutz.de` domain

Comment: I changed to CDN but still showing error

Comment: Try loading all the resources from `https` instead of `http`

Comment: tried but still not resolved